How to fix fraction horizontal rule?
Below fraction is my source input. i want to short horizontal rule. Can anyone please advise. I have attached both input and expecting output images:

and the tex source code is:
\[\frac{\overbrace{A}^{\text{detector area}}}{\underbrace{4\pi}_{\text{unit solid angle}}}\]

An expected output is:


Load mathtools and use \mathclap{\text{....}} instead of \text{...}

Have you tried having the over/under brace outside of the fraction?

@daleif i will check and get back. Thanks

@Teepeemm Sorry. i am not clear. Can you please give me some sample code?

@daleif - Wow It's amazing. I got expected output. Thanks for the coding.
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\[\frac{\overbrace{A}^{\mathclap{\text{detector area}}}}{\underbrace{4\pi}_{\mathclap{\text{unit solid angle}}}}\]
\end{document}

@KGSR as you can see comments are not well suited for longer pieces of code

@daleif - suggested result:

The tex code is:
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\[\frac{\overbrace{A}^{\mathclap{\text{detector area}}}}{\underbrace{4\pi}_{\mathclap{\text{unit solid angle}}}}\]

\end{document}


You can just use \clap{...} without a need of mathtools and \mathclap{\text{...}}

This works only if the fraction is the only item in the display. If it's part of an expression, you'd get overlaps.

I have tried an another way and got the same output. But i used \rule command with some manual work:
\[
{\begin{array}{@{}c@{}}
{\overbrace{A}^{\text{detector area}}}\\[-6pt]
\rule{13pt}{0.25pt}\\[-1.5pt]{\underbrace{4\pi}_{\text{unit solid angle}}}
\end{array}}
\]

Output is:

Finally, @daleif suggested code is great one (automatically output came). I Thanks once again both @daleif & @Teepeemm for spending times with me.
